# Custom image size not regenerating when image editted

Tags: images, cropping

I have a custom image size at 200x150 that works fine in a plugin I'm working on.  Uploading new files is no problem but when I edit an image, the default image sizes get regenerated but my custom size does not.  Is there a way to force the regeneration programatically in a filter or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To regenerate custom image size when image is edited in image editor , You have to add following options in wp_options table using update_option function along with add_image_size.

**Example :**

```
$img_size_name = 'custom-size'; // The new image size name.
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) )
add_image_size($img_size_name, 100, 100 , true);

update_option($img_size_name.'_size_w', 100);
update_option($img_size_name.'_size_h', 100);
update_option($img_size_name.'_crop', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it.  It's weird that `add_image_size` doesn't do this by default.  Sounds like the function needs to be expanded.

Comment: This may have worked for whatever version of WordPress the questions is referring. Recent versions of WordPress ( I'm thinking 3.9 on ) will auto-regenerate custom images and default images *if* the `Apply to all images` radio button is checked ( whenever editing the image ). The apply option will also **only be available** if the post type has a `thumbnail` size, so the niche cases where your post type doesn't have a thumbnail size - this option will not show up and you'll run into issues.