# Image rotation fails to regenerate custom sized thumbnail

Tags: functions, attachments, theme-options, images

I'm using custom image dimensions in functions.php like this:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size-thumbnail', 120, 120, true );
```

I uploaded some pictures with wrong orientation, so I used "edit" options to rotate them...

Problem is, that only original size pictures (full, large, medium, thumbnail) are regenerated (as a new file in the FTP directory - original picture.jpg, rotated picture-e1384125509778.jpg). My custom sized, however, are not :-( (no new file is created, theme is still loading one with wrong orientation).

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you regenerating Thumbnails?

Comment: No special steps - just wp-admin built-in image editor does it itself when you modify picture...

Comment: WordPress doesn't *regenerate* intermediate image sizes. It only creates them on image upload/attachment post creation.

Comment: Use a plugin like Simple Image Size to regenerate thumbnails manually (the plugin could do it in batch, don't worry).

Answer (score 1):

Asked the same question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89925/custom-image-size-not-regenerating-when-image-editted).  There is an extra step to fix this, as answered in my question.

Answer (score 0):

[Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) or [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) should solve your problem.